# Encoding RGB frames using x264 and AVCodec in C

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rgb, libavcodec, x264

I have RGB24 frames streamed from camera and i want to encode them into h264 ,i found that AVCodec and x264 can do so, the problem is x264 as default accepts YUV420 as input so what i wrote was a program which convert RGB frames to YUV420 .that was by sws_scale function .this works well except that it does not satisfy the required FPS because the converting (RGB->YUV420) takes time.

This is how i setup my encoder context :

```
videoStream->id = 0;
vCodecCtx = videoStream->codec;

vCodecCtx->coder_type       = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
vCodecCtx->codec_id         = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
vCodecCtx->bit_rate         = 400000;
vCodecCtx->width            = Width;
vCodecCtx->height           = Height;
vCodecCtx->time_base.den    = FPS;
vCodecCtx->time_base.num    = 1;
//vCodecCtx->time_base      = (AVRational){1,};
vCodecCtx->gop_size         = 12;
vCodecCtx->max_b_frames     = 1;
vCodecCtx->pix_fmt          = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

if(formatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    vCodecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

av_opt_set(vCodecCtx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(vCodecCtx->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);

if (avcodec_open2(vCodecCtx, h264Codec, NULL) < 0){
    return 0;
}
```

when i changes AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P to AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 ,avcodec_open2 will fail.
i read that there is a version of libx264 for RGB called libx264rgb but i even dont know whether i have to rebuild x264 with enabling this option or to download another source or i have to do it programmatically with the first x264 lib.

the question is how to enable RGB as input to libx264 to use with libavcodec in C .or how to make the encoding or sws_scale more fast .

Edit:

How i built ffmpeg :

```
NDK=D:/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r9
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

GENERAL="\
--enable-small \
--enable-cross-compile \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
--arch=arm \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--extra-cflags="-I../x264/android/arm/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L../x264/android/arm/lib" "


MODULES="\
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264"

function build_ARMv6
{
  ./configure \
  --target-os=linux \
  --prefix=./android/armeabi \
  ${GENERAL} \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-static \
  --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=armv6" \
  --extra-ldflags="-lx264 -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
  --enable-zlib \
  ${MODULES} \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-neon

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_ARMv6

echo Android ARMEABI builds finished
```

How i built x264 :

```
NDK=D:/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r9
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
PREFIX=./android/arm

function build_one
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --host=arm-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_one

echo Android ARM builds finished
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use RGB pixel formats (AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24) with libx264 in libavcodec you need:

1. use libavcodec from ffmpeg project and not from libav project because currently it is only available in there;
2. make sure that libavcodec was compiled with libx264rgb (CONFIG_LIBX264RGB_ENCODER) which as I understand would be enabled if you would use new enough 8-bit libx264 (configured with --enable-libx264);
3. use avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264rgb") instead of avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264).

Comment: ok ,the 1,2 steps are already done , now i got the encoder using avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264rgb") instead of avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264) and used the same code above to setup my encoder context with changing pix_fmt to AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 , But avcodec_open2 fails , i tried another pix_fmt (AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 , and even AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) but avcodec_open2 still fails ,the returned error value is -22 ,( i think it means "invalid argument" ).

Comment: i am not sure about second step if my x264 is new enough , and what do you mean by 8-bit

Comment: Have you checked that result of avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264rgb") is not NULL? "New enough" mean something not outdated like 5 years old version before API 117. "8-bit" means supported bitdepth and can me from 8 to 10 in libx264 (only one bitdepth can be supported simultaneously and configured during compilation). Do you compile libx264 and ffmpeg yourself or take some precompiled version?

Comment: Looks like ffmpeg can fail to detect libx264rgb if x264.h is not in headers search paths even if it detects libx264 itself with pkgconfig. So you need to explicitly add path to x264.h when compiling ffmpeg by using something like: --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include"

Comment: yes i checked avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264rgb") , it is not NULL . I compiled them myself using the configuration above (see my edit)

Comment: may be i could figure out the problem,if i compared my code with a worked  x264 example for RGB ,can you bring me one if you have so.

Comment: i found the problem ,this line av_opt_set(vCodecCtx->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN); should be removed.

Comment: @nobody555 You were right, I also had to set extra ```--extra-cflags="-I../x264/dist/include" \ --extra-ldflags="-L../x264/dist/lib" \```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own RGB2YUV decoder.

Get pixel map from the frame and run it through your function. No scaling, no nothing, just one for loop.

There are easy formulae to convert RGB888  to YCbCr (YUV4:4:4).

But AV/FFMpeg should be able to do it for you easily.

For YUV420 you'll need to get whole 4:4:4 Y channel, and interpolate every 4 pixels into U and V , using either mean or gaussian, to get 4:2:0.

Like this:

This code expects ABC4:4:4 CB or Cr channel and returns its ABC4:2:0 version of it.

```
#define uint8 unsigned char
uint8 *ABC_444_to_420 (uint8 *src, uint8 *dst, int w, int h) {
    int dpos, x, y, pl1, pl2;
    dpos = 0;
    for (x=0; x<h; x+=2) {
        for (y=0; y<w; y+=2) {
            pl1 = x*w+y; pl2 = (x+1)*w+y;
            dst[dpos] = (src[pl1]+src[pl1+1]+src[pl2]+src[pl2+1])>>2;
            dpos += 1;
            }
        }
    return dst;
    }
```

So, you get YUV444 from RGB, then run U and V through code above separately.

If you cannot find appropriate function from AV/FFMpeg that will convert RGB to YCbCr take a look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You may, of course, put whole process into one passthrough at RGB to YCbCr conversion, to get ABC4:2:0 out directly.

Do not work directly on AV/FFMpeg frame pixels, get your self raw data in an array. Then you'll get maximum speed, then construct AV/FFMpeg Frame back from the results.

Comment: By the way, most cameras should be able to give you YCbCr format directly, so snoop out for camera modes. Some cameras can even give you YUV12 i.e. ABC4:2:0 that you need. Hope so, then no transforms are necessary.  Just set the camera to proper mode and push data to the encoder.

Comment: First,thank you for your efforts to help . about the convertion i dont understand the structure of YUV420 to write the full conversion function , i tried  a prepared external function from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465815/rgb-to-yuv420-algorithm-efficiency) but it seems that sws_scale was fast or almost the same speed.

Comment: you are right that most cameras gives YCbCr format directly, but i am using opengl to do some effects , so the camera writes the pixels directly to a opengl texture as rgb .After applying effects , i read pixels from the texture as rgb .

Comment: YCbCr 3 channels/planes work as follows:
Y represents intensity/luminosity (so called luma channel) and you can say that it is a gray scale representation of the color image.
Cb is chroma blue difference channel, and Cr is chroma red difference channel.
When we have gamma corrected images (mostly photos) then YCbCr is non-linear and Cb and Cr can be called U and V, therefore YUV.
Those stupid YUV numbers represent ratio in downsampling.
In natural photos there are no rough edges, which means that neighboring pixels have very similar colour, but a little different luminosity.

Comment: Using this property we can have full resolution Y with all pixels needed but apply same colour difference (regulated by Cb and Cr) to more than one neighboring Y pixel.
And this will not much influence quality of an image.
This is what happens with YUV420. It means that for 4 Y pixels you have 1 Cb & Cr definition. So Y is 4 times bigger than Cb or Cr.
My code takes full Y~CbCr i.e. YUV444 U or V channel and downsamples it to 420. I.e. it takes a mean out of each 4 neighboring pixels.

Comment: I already explained how to get YUV444. You iterate over RGB image pixel by pixel and apply the formulae from the link in the answer, thus getting value for Y, Cb and Cr from RGB values.
It may be that the code you used gets a little bit better quality or it is slightly faster than first getting YUV444, then downsampling U and V to get YUV420, but nothing drastic, believe me.
You can get a little bit faster results by using hardware acceleration, but I think that your speed problem is with h264 encoder, not RGB to YUV transformation.

Comment: If i will use FFmpeg to convert from rgb to yuv444 ,why do not i use FFmpeg sws_scale function to convert directly from rgb to yuv420 ,is the conversion from yuv444 to yuv420 what takes the whole time ?I prefer to avoid the conversion and encode rgb directly . is there any disadvantage when i encode h264 as rgb instead of yuv420 ?

Comment: I don't know why the function in question should be slow. I think you have other speed issues, or perhaps you activated rescaling (resizing), which can take time. Or it does run the image through some unnecessary filters or whatever. The code I provided is very quick and adds almost nothing to YUV444 transformation, so, in theory you should use FFMpeg to get YUV420 directly, but you say that it doesn't work fast enough. Almost all video formats do use YUV as base  frame format. Hardware accelerated video surfaces on which videos are projected expect YUV input.

Comment: So when you want to play video in real time, no more transforms are needed. Decoder gets you out YUV frame and you push it to HW Overlay to display it. All time loss goes to IO and decompression. So, to get H264 video frame you need YUV format. Even if FFMpeg/AV can give you encoder with RGB input, encoder will be performing RGB 2 YUV420, either as a first step or on the fly.

Comment: Also, look up what OpenGL gives you. It may be that it has RGB to YUV transforming function. Somewhere in colorspaces. See, all operations that can be done on RGB colorspace can be done on YUV or CMYK directly. Some operations would be faster in one colorspace than in other, but it can be done. OpenGL should give you that option as well. So you should be able to get YUV from camera and apply your texture on it as it is, and then push it to FFMpeg.